# Get correct characters from barcode reader independent on input method

Tags: c#, windows-10, barcode-scanner

I've a problem with barcode readers: if I have a barcode reader with setted country USA and the input language on my PC (Windows 10) is Italian, when I scan a code with special characters (like \ / : ) I'll see at video other characters (like ù - ç).

If I install and change my input method to USA, it reads characters correctly.
Otherwise, if I change country on barcode reader in Italy and leave input method on PC Italian it reads characters correctly.

I can't install USA input method dynamically on customer's PCs and I can't know how barcode readers will be programmed so there's a simple solution to get the correct characters sequence without change input methods and barcode reader's settings??

Comment: Isn't it impossible as long as you use the keyboard input emulation method? Either print out the setting barcode at the place where it will be installed or used, or change to the serial interface method.

Comment: Can we see the code that's doing the reading?

Comment: The code I have to read is **\ / : * ? < > |** and my PC reads **ù - ç ( _ ° ; : §**